# Replace a pattern with the output of a command in sed

Tags: bash, sed

Suppose I have some text file (json in this case):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1577856103107
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1577869991302
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to replace a pattern (in this case a UNIX millisecond timestamp) with a more readable date format.

I'm trying with this:

```sh
$ sed -E 's/(.*)([0-9]{13})/echo "\1\\"$(date --date="@$((\2\/1000))" --iso-8601=seconds)\\""/e' example.json

{
  "data": [
    {
      timestamp: "2020-01-01T00:21:43-05:00"
    },
    {
      timestamp: "2020-01-01T04:13:11-05:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is somewhat ok, but I don't understand why the quotes arround `timestamp` get lost.

This command works:

```sh
sed -E 's/(.*)"(timestamp)"(: )([0-9]{13})/echo "\1\\"\2\\"\3\\"$(date --date="@$((\4\/1000))" --iso-8601=seconds)"\\"/e' example.json

{
  "data": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:21:43-05:00"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "2020-01-01T04:13:11-05:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I also don't understand why I need double backslashes `\\` to ouput a double-quote `"` in the right side of this sed command.

Is there a better way (or tool) to solve this?

I'm on `sed (GNU sed) 4.8` and `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way (or tool) to solve this?

Using `sed` for manipulating json things is very crude. You can't parse json with regex. I (strongly) suggest to use json-aware tools, like `jq`.

```
jq '.data[].timestamp |= (. / 1000 | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))'
```

> but I don't understand why the quotes arround timestamp get lost.

The:

```
echo "\1\\"$(date --date="@$((\2\/1000))" --iso-8601=seconds)\\""
```

is "substituted" to:

```
echo ""timestamp": \"$(date --date="@$((1577856103107/1000))" --iso-8601=seconds)\""
     ^^
                ^------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Then is passed to shell and quotes are re-evalulated according to shell rules.

Matching `(.*)` is really doing nothing, just match only the part you want to substitute. You could instead match only the part you want to substitute:

```
sed '/"timestamp":/s/([0-9]{13})/echo "\\"$(date --date="@$((\1\/1000))" --iso-8601=seconds)\\""/e'
```

> why I need double backslashes \ to ouput a double-quote " in the right side of this sed command.

First `\\` is interpreted by `sed` into single `\`.

```
$ echo a | sed 's/.*/single slash: \\/'
single slash: \
```

Then *the result* of `sed` command is passed to shell where all shell parsing rules are done one again.